# Kubuntu: application windows freeze/become-disabled, but menus and keyboard shortcuts still work

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, kde4, xorg-edgers

Lately some of my applications have been semi-freezing at random times. I've noticed this using Chromium, Blender and Sublime Text, with Chromium by far having the most occurrences. Basically, the window part of the application will stop updating and become unresponsive, but the application can still be controlled with keyboard shortcuts and through the menus. Once I quit out of the program, it will be fine on restart.

Most of the time it happens after switching back to an application from another, but it's also happened while I've been actively editing in a window. When it happens in one window of an application, other windows are not effected.

Has anyone else had a similar experience? If so, have you been able to fix it or find the cause? I know Blender and Sublime Text are both Python, so it could have something to do with that.

I'm running Kubuntu 16.04/Xenial with a GeForce GTX 970 (these seem like the most important specs for the issue, but I an provide more if necessary).

Edit: I think my idea that it could have something to do with Python was incorrect. I've experienced the issue in Firefox and while playing X-Com 2 now. X-Com 2 froze during a cut scene, w/ just the edges of the screen being updated, but the audio continued playing. Tabbing out from the full screen view and then returning to the game would show a new frame from the full cut scene movie, but it was still frozen there. I also noticed that after resizing a Chromium or Firefox window, the window will redraw (I'd entered content in a text field and saw it there after the resize). I ran ppa-purge on my xorg-edgers drivers and reinstalled them, so maybe that will help.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on two different computers with Kubuntu 16.04 and Nvidia drivers.